# javascript backbone dynamic content append prevent jump to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am currently using backbone to render a view. I have set an interval to update and pull the latest json, it then appends the changes and updates the corresponding DOM elements.

The problem I seem to be facing is that whenever it empties the container and then re-populates it with the updated info, it jumps to the top of the page. Is there something I can change in my view to make sure it doesnt jump after I append?

Answer (score 0):

You can override your view's `render()` method, or you can register an event handler for the appropriate `change` event to handle an incremental render. Without examples, it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is the content is momentarily removed, making the page shorter. The browser window is pushed up for a tiny moment, then the new content is appended, making the page longer again.

To test, try making your browser window very short and triggering the update. If the page doesn't jump, this is your issue.

I'm dealing with the same thing myself right now. My solution is to read the height of the parent element before removal, set it, then clear the set height when the new content is appended.